# Trouble reading C bmp into memory

Tags: c, bmp

I am trying to read a .bmp header into memory. I am getting a core dump when I run the program.

```
BMP_Image *Read_BMP_Header(FILE* fptr) {

    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    BMP_Image *bmp_image = NULL;

    bmp_image = malloc(sizeof(BMP_Header));
    fread(&bmp_image->header, sizeof(BMP_Header), 1, fptr);
    return bmp_image;
}
```

The error at the fread.

The header structure is:

```
typedef struct _BMP_Header
{
    uint16_t type;          // Magic identifier
    uint32_t size;          // File size in bytes
    uint16_t reserved1;         // Not used
    uint16_t reserved2;         // Not used
    uint32_t offset;            // Offset to image data in bytes from beginning of file (54 bytes)
    uint32_t DIB_header_size;       // DIB Header size in bytes (40 bytes)
    int32_t  width;         // Width of the image
    int32_t  height;            // Height of image
    uint16_t planes;            // Number of color planes
    uint16_t bits;          // Bits per pixel
    uint32_t compression;       // Compression type
    uint32_t imagesize;         // Image size in bytes
    int32_t  xresolution;       // Pixels per meter
    int32_t  yresolution;       // Pixels per meter
    uint32_t ncolours;          // Number of colors  
    uint32_t importantcolours;      // Important colors 
} BMP_Header;
```

and the image structure is:

```
typedef struct _BMP_Image {
    BMP_Header header;
    unsigned char *data; 
} BMP_Image;
```

Comment: You never check the return value of any of the functions you use, `malloc()` returns `NULL` on failure, `fread()` should return `1` in this case (read some manual for more information).

Comment: I edited the code to check for those failures and I still got a core dump. Do you have any other ideas for what it could be?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It should be fptr. I don't know why it showed up as fptr but I just check and I did have fptr. That is strange though.

Comment: I see no error in the `fread` that would cause a crash. iharob is right that you didn't allocate enough memory for the struct, but you did allocate enough for the `fread`. So I question your assertion that the `fread` causes the crash. In any case, you need to make sure that the `BMP_Header` is packed, otherwise the structure padding *will* cause problems.

Comment: I am aware of that. I have the following line in my header file: `#pragma pack(1)`

Comment: which line goes bang? run it under a debugger

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is

```
bmp_image = malloc(sizeof(BMP_Header));
```

it should be

```
bmp_image = malloc(sizeof(BMP_Image));
```

you can avoid this kind of mistake like this

```
bmp_image = malloc(sizeof(*bmp_image));
```

The reasons why this might fail may be many, but it's certainly wrong because you are allocating space for a `BMP_Header *` but pointing to it with a `BMP_Image *` which is a structure of different size. Dereferencing the pointer becomes undefined behavior os you can't guarantee a given behavior.

Comment: I just tried both BMP_Image and *bmp_image and neither of them worked. I still got a core dump. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Does it crash on the same line?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It crashes on the fread line. I ran valgrind and it tells me that I have an invalid read size of 2 if that helps

Comment: You must post the `fopen()` line, I suspect you didn't check for that either.

Comment: @iharob I am having trouble posting a chunk of code as a comment but:
      FILE *fptr;
      char *filename = "photo.bmp";
      fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
      if (fptr == NULL)
      {`   
          fprintf(stderr, "\nInvalid file\n");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }

Comment: How about you post a small-as-possible complete program so people don't have to guess?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to multiply the imagesize with sizeof(unsigned char) and the same when I was reading it in. I honestly don't know why this would matter but I got it to work.

Comment: That is certainly incorrect because `sizeof(unsigned char)` is going to be always **1**!!!! You have undefined behavior, and still have it.